# Is This Feasible - Running MailWash on a dedicated machine to pre-check

Tags: email, outlook, spam, spam-filter

Is This Feasible - Running MailWash on a dedicated machine to pre-check 80-100 email accounts before end-users check with Outlook?

We have some major SPAM issues at my company with some users receiving over 1000 SPAM messages per day.  Our mail is web-based and managed by a local ISP that does not offer any SPAM filtering at all.  All user are required to check their mail with Outlook 2003/2007.

What are some of the issues that I might face if I run MailWAsh on a dedicated machine to precheck everyones mail numerous times per day.  If you arent familiar with MailWash, thats exactly what it does, although it is meant to run locally on each machine.  It prechecks mail, weeds out SPAM, and leaves legimate mail.  When the user send/receives in Outlook, they hopefully receive only the legit mail left on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's pretty much the same way that I have my family's postfix/linux mail server set; due to some bad filtering when I first started, mailscanner/clamav simply flags the message as spam and gives it a meta heading with a spam score. When the user's client accesses it, a rule in the client filters the spam into the trash bin automatically where the user can retrieve it if they think it was a false positive.

Now, a better solution would be to switch to a host that at least scans your incoming mail, or if you have control over your DNS zone, then you could always just route your mail through a server that you have set up with mailscanner or similar, strip/quarantine the mail, and THEN roue to the Exchange server.

Comment: I agree with the better solution:  set up a filtering/scanning mx gateway to receive all your mail, and have it flag likely spam in the header before it forwards it on to your "real" (ISP's) mailserver.

I used to do this years ago with Fluffy the SMTP Guard Dog http://smtpfilter.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

We started off with MailWasher on each individual machine and then using OE to get the washed mail. I don't think it supports multiple accounts though.
Your best bet would be getting a dedicated mail server and stick a gateway washer on there. I recommend [ORF](http://www.vamsoft.com/default.asp)